# Has anyone had any problems with CNAs (Converged Network Adapters)?

Tags: 10gbethernet, cisco-nexus

I'm looking to buy some CNAs to trial with, probably the Emulex board. Just wondering if anyone's using these cards or any competing cards and if so have you have any problems with them yet? In particular with stability, timeouts or high host CPU utilisation.

Oh this will be a mixed test of W2K8, RHEL 5U3 and ESX 3.5U4 via a Cisco Nexus 7K/5K.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do have data corruption problems with the Mellanox ConnectX cards with RHEL5U3. Tried various drivers (RH, Oracle, Mellanox) - all have different issues.

A progress is visible with bleeding edge drivers, though, so I guess these problems will be sorted out soon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the QLogic 8200 CNA? We are running it in a W2K8 Virtialized ESX environment without any problems. Partitioning of the adapters is set up with prioritization on Apps and with support for mobility of the VM OSs.

Answer (score 0):

The QLogic QLE8152 is our workhorse and is about $1000.  I suggest avoiding the 8200 series, unless you want to offload iSCSI, as we've had several issues with the couple we have, even after applying this [manditory cricial](http://bit.ly/qXkvfb) update.